# How can I add html to this php echo won't work

Tags: php

This is really annoying, echo won't work and putting the html outside the php won't work either, I need help on this badly because I'm trying to make an announcement system.

```html
<?php


echo $_POST['aapassword'];
$aapass = "xs4qxt3ggs4o3";

if ($password == $aapass) {
    <<<END
        <form action="anouncements.php" method="post">
        Add your announcement: <input type="input" name="aaannouncement">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                                  
        
        END;
} else {
echo("incorrect password");
}


<<<END
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="announcements/add-announcement.php" method="post">
    Password:  <input type="password" name="aapassword" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    
    <h1>Hi</h1>
</form>
</body>
END;

?>
```

Comment: it's your heredoc; parse error.

Comment: `echo <<<END`. you're heredoccing into nothingness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the spaces before your closing heredoc identifier?

```
        END;
```

There are 8 of them.

There should not be anything before and/or after it.

- Remove them.
- https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> **Warning**
>
> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

---

- Error reporting would have thrown you a parse error.
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Plus, put all your elements inside one set of form tags, not two, unless that's what the ultimate goal is.

---

I noticed you are storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case and are not planning on using a hash, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).